# BIOS Video memory interaction position calculation weirdly

Tags: c, kernel, bios, video-memory

I have written a very simple kernel that loads inside QEMU with the help of GRUB. I probably have a problem in pointer calculation, but cannot really figure out what is wrong.

The following code works as expected, it prints the given character.

```
char* video = 0xb8000 + 0;
char* color = 'A';

*video++ = c;
*video++ = color;
```

However when I change the video pointer calculation to this it does not work, nothing appears on screen:

```
int pos = 0;
char* video = 0xb8000 + pos;
```

But when I make the pos variable unsigned int, it works uncorrectly, but when I make it 1, it works as the first one, but why it needs to be 1?

```
unsigned int pos = 1;
char* video = 0xb8000 + pos;
```

My C flags: `CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -nostdlib -ffreestanding -g`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `char color = 'A'` (instead of a pointer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try prefixing it like this: (char*)0xB8000

```
char* video = (char*)0xB8000;
int pos = 0;

video[pos++] = 'A';
video[pos++] = 0x7;
```

Comment: This made me aware that I was using the color & character wrong, the order should be reverse, first color then character! Thanks

Comment: First (low) byte - ASCII character, second (high) byte - attributes (colour, blinking etc)

Comment: Oh, I used this: `char* video = (char*)0xB8000;video[2 * pos] = c; video[2 * pos + 1] = color;`but the last character is always wrong attribute, what is wrong?

Comment: It seems like it is fixed when I made it offset by 1, it all suddenly work!